# Is it poor grammar to replace normal phrases with mathematical symbols in sentences in a mathematical paper?

Tags: mathematics, writing-style, grammar

English is not my native language and when I read mathematical papers, sometimes I saw sentences such as

> The matrix A has rank ≥ n.

I am wondering if this sentence should be considered as grammatically wrong. I think the correct expression should be

> The rank of the matrix A is greater than or equal to n.

Are expressions such as "The matrix A has rank ≥ n" considered as acceptable in mathematical papers/theses/textbooks?

Comment: I've never seen an argument against it, @Zuriel. On the other hand, I don't read mathematical papers. My main disagreement with your both of your examples is the phrase *the matrix A*. I would say either *the matrix* or *matrix A*. (The *A* is used to specify the matrix in question; the *the* is used to indicate that you are talking about a previously specified matrix. Combining the two seems clumsy.)

Comment: @TRiG, I see! Many thanks for the clarification! It is now very clear to me.

Comment: @TRiG I disagree. Your example without "the" would be grammatically incorrect. In the example at hand I would write "at least" rather than either suggestion.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [english.se], not academia

Comment: I don't think this is a good fit for English Language & Usage (it's more about academic writing conventions than the English language).  One could debate whether it fits better here or on math.stackexchange.com, but I think it's fine here (and indeed this issue comes up in more fields than just mathematics).

Comment: @TRiG I would say 'the matrix A' is correct (and frequently used). I wouldn't say 'Matrix A' is incorrect, but I think it's less common. On the otherhand, there definitely is an argument against using the ≥ sign, namely that it is not formal English, rather a form of short-hand.

Comment: The first of your two sentences looks fine to me. The second seems long-winded; I'd replace "greater than or equal to n" with "at least n" or with "n or more".

Comment: What makes you consider the first sentence ungrammatical?  It seems fine to me.

Comment: 1. This question seems off-topic for Academia, because it is about the content of a particular field, rather than the process.  This question belongs on Math.SE (if it belongs anywhere), where those who are expert on Mathematics can judge the stylistic issue. 2. The question does not show any evidence of prior research. We expect people to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in the question where they've looked. There are plenty of math style guides that provide guidance on this; the author should have searched for them before asking.

Comment: @D.W.: This question is about mathematical equations in academic writing: the scope of that is beyond one academic field.  "We expect people to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us in the question where they've looked."  I don't think that the majority of questions asked here meet that standard.  You are right though that the issue is covered in math style guides; an answer which includes a reference to one would be helpful.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, doing research before asking is a StackExchange expectation: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723.

Comment: I agree that doing some research makes a question better, and the site FAQ includes this information.  What you wrote is significantly stronger than this.  Well over half of all questions asked here do not show "evidence of prior research", so that is evidently not the community standard for closing a question.  We also clearly do not close questions because an answer has been written down *somewhere*.  If you feel that an obvious internet search should answer the question, could you include a link which demonstrates this?

Comment: @D.W. Mathematics is far from being the only science where you can choose between written and symbolic form of something, physics, chemistry, biology and probably others can face the problem as well. And for "not showing research effort" -- IMHO, this is applicable only in cases where it's simple to show research effort, e.g., when the answer is plain in the corresponding wikipedia page. I'm not keen on seeing in every question a proof of research effort, or do you want everywhere something like: "I have tried the following 178 Google search terms and I didn't fin anything?"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Are expressions such as "The matrix A has rank ≥ n" considered as acceptable in mathematical papers/theses/textbooks?

No, it's often considered poor style to incorporate fragments of equations like this into text.  I wouldn't go so far as to say it's ungrammatical, but many people consider it bad writing.  Some others don't care about this issue, which is why you sometimes see it done, but this is more common in informal or unedited writing.

The issue is that "rank ≥ n" is mixing together English and mathematics within the same construction.  If this doesn't bother you, imagine a more dramatic case like "n + five".  (By contrast, when someone writes "if x ≥ y", the inequality "x ≥ y" is a self-contained unit within the sentence.)  There's no logical reason why mathematical writing conventions couldn't allow this sort of mixing, but they don't.

Saying "The matrix A has rank at least n" is shorter and cleaner than "The rank of the matrix A is greater than or equal to n", but they are both acceptable.  I'd recommend avoiding "The matrix A has rank ≥ n" (I can't think of a good reason to prefer it, and avoiding looking bad is a reason not to use it).

Comment: At least here, you could write "For matrix A, rank(A) > n," and avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: @aeismail: not the best choice: you have then two equations seperated only by a comma.  It would be better to write e.g. "For matrix A, the inequality rank(A)>n holds." or something like that.

Comment: @aeismail Eeeew. That's just awful.  I vote for "Matrix A has rank at least n."

Comment: @mbork: What is the other equation?

Comment: @aeismail Having only a comma separating the two mathematical expressions $A$ and $rank(A)>n$ is at issue.  I agree with mbork.

Comment: @aeismail: "expression" or "formula" would probably a better word, sorry.

Comment: I would say that "matrix" needs an article: "for the/a matrix $A$...". That said, my suggestion is "We have $\operatorname{rank} A \geq n$.", or "It holds that $\operatorname{rank} A \geq n$.". The formula alone would be enough, but another common style rule is 'never start a sentence with a symbol'.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Not necessarily. I'm not an expert, but when the name is given (`A` in this case), you don't need the article. At least that's what one Language Editor told me.

Comment: @yo': It's more of a style issue than a language issue.  Starting a sentence with a mathematical expression is discouraged.  Starting with "The matrix $A$" instead of just "$A$" fixes that.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang However, it doesn't say you can start the sentence with: "Matrix $A$".

Comment: @yo': I agree..

Comment: @yo': To my ear, "Matrix $A$ has rank..." sounds like it was written by a non-native English speaker (despite the fact that at least one native speaker supports it).  It's a subtle issue: the name of the matrix is not "Matrix $A$", it's "$A$".  The word "matrix" has been added so as not to begin a sentence, clause or phrase with a mathematical symbol.  Saying "Matrix $A$" instead of "The matrix $A$"  carries a whiff of anthropomorphism.  I guess I am also a little annoyed at the amount of "article dropping" that takes place in math papers, so I would not want to sound like an article-dropper.

Comment: @Pete To me the phrase "Matrix A..." sounds a bit like "Door 2..." (or at least that is the closest I can get to making it not sound like something is missing). But then again, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'd like it if all the native speakers specified US or UK (which may or may not be different; I don't know).  For example, I'm a native speaker from the US and "Matrix A" sounds more natural to me than "The matrix A"

Comment: If I read a sentence starting "For matrix A..." instead of "For the matrix A" I would definitely assume the speaker was not a native American English speaker.  Sesame Street doesn't say "This episode was brought to you by letter A and number 5."

Comment: I definitely wouldn't say "matrix A" with no article.  Typically the article is dropped for titles but not descriptions.  You say "Professor Smith" (not "the Professor Smith") or "Theorem 1.2", but "the mathematician Smith" or "the matrix A".  Here A is the full and complete name of the matrix, and adding "the matrix" is just to clarify (in particular, it doesn't have the title "Matrix A").  I'd bet this is why "Matrix A" comes across as anthropomorphism to Pete Clark, although there are non-anthropomorphic examples like "Chapter 2" or, in a Monty Hall-style game show, "Door 2".

Comment: I think the distinction is that titles function as part of names, and names don't get articles.  So from this perspective, the article is either mandatory or not allowed, depending on how you interpret the role of "matrix".  At least in my experience in pure mathematics, labels for parts of the paper (sections, equations, etc.) have the relevant noun as part of their name, but mathematical objects such as matrices do not.

Comment: @NoahSnyder That's not a good comparison though, because there is only one "letter A" and one "number 5".  To borrow AnonymousMathematician's words, "matrix A" is a description, not a title, because "matrix A" is different in different equations - that's why dropping the article makes sense.

Comment: If it's a description, that's exactly when you *can't* drop the article.  In the alphabet, "A" is the name of the letter, not "Letter A" (and if you want to clarify that you're talking about a letter, you need to say "the letter A").  Similarly, in the mathematical example A is the name of the matrix, not "Matrix A".

Comment: @Pete L. Clark (and others stumbling upon these comments): This question was recently bumped to the front page of Academia (why I'm commenting nearly 7 years later), and to me a much more crucial issue with "The matrix A has rank ≥ n" is that 'A' is the name of a matrix but '≥ n' is not the name of a rank. When I first read this sentence in the question I was confused for a moment because I was expecting a number ("numeral", if we're going to nitpick) and had to go back and begin reading again before I realized that ≥ wasn't a stray symbol. It only took 2-3 seconds, but I found it irritating.

Answer (score 19):

*(Copy Editor and mathematician speaking)*

I, for one, allow these mixed constructions when editing the articles. I do know that it is not the best grammatical style, but not everything in math is easy to put down in proper English grammar. The two rules of thumb I use for these boundary cases is: Is the text clear to the reader? Can you *easily* make it grammatically correct?

For instance, the sentence "For matrix A, the equation rank(A) ≥ 5 holds." is cryptic and long. A better option might be "For matrix A, we have rank(A) ≥ 5." or "Matrix A satisfies rank(A) ≥ 5." I would be fine with "Matrix A has rank at least 5." However, this gets complicated if you have more such expressions in a row, like in:

> ... which is defined as a non-real algebraic integer in modulus >1 whose Galois conjugates except its complex conjugate are in modulus <1.

vs.

> ... which is defined as a non-real algebraic integer in modulus greater than 1 whose Galois conjugates except its complex conjugate are in modulus less than 1.

I prefer the first option. This went through the AMS language editorial, as far as I remember, without any problem.

Answer (score 7):

I let it pass if the sentence is unambiguous and can be pronounced normally when reading without any special effort like in "If $A$ is $\ge B+C$ and $f:[0,A]\to\mathbb Z$, then... (If the quantity/parameter/number $A$ is larger than the sum $B+C$ and the function $f$ maps the interval $[0,A]$ to the set $\mathbb Z$, then...) because in this case the extra words just slow the reader down. However, when seeing any ambiguity like "If A, B, C." (which comma is "and", and which is "then" here?) or something that, if attempted to be read as a sentence, violates not only the rules of the grammar, but also those of common sense as far as structuring sentences is concerned and which, if one needs it to be said at the board in a classroom, will have to be split into separate sentences and totally restructured to be comprehended by ear, I usually object.

Side note: what's the point of not enabling mathjax on Academia?

Comment: I love your side note!

Comment: upvoting the side note, but I can guess the limited audience (within academia.SX) needing it works against it.

Comment: The nice thing about mathjax, however, is that if there is no LaTeX code in the post, it is not even invoked, so what is there to lose? Anyway, that should rather be discussed on Meta from this point on :-)

Comment: If you support adding mathjax to the site, please weigh in at http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/740/mathjax-on-academia.  Apparently the point of not having it is that it one has to petition the SE administration to get it and there is concern that it will happen more often that people who don't know about mathjax will want to include two dollar signs on the same line more often than people will want to include mathematical equations.  This is basically an argument from ignorance...

Answer (score 2):

In principle, it is generally acceptable to mix together mathematical and prose statements, as in your example: either construction would be technically be grammatically correct.

In practice, which to choose depends on how you want your reader to think about the statement that you have written.  Prose emphasizes the relationship, in your example focusing the reader on "greater than."  A mathematical statement tends to instead be thought of as a unit, in your example focusing the reader on "rank."  You should thus choose accordingly.

One exception: small integers referring to counting within a small range should always be written as prose.  Some examples of this distinction:

> We selected eight conditions to test.
>
> We found that 8 of the 73 samples were positive.

The boundary of "small" is a bit hazy: certainly less than 10, usually less than 20.

Comment: _it is generally acceptable_ — [citation needed]

Comment: @JeffE My reviewers don't seem to complain when I do it in good taste.

Comment: @jakebeal Reviewers rarely, in my experience, comment on writing style, except for egregious errors. All the advice I've seen on mathematican writing recommends *not* mixing words and symbols as in "the rank is >2".

Comment: @DavidRicherby Perhaps we have different experiences in our different communities - with some conference and journals, I often receive detailed remarks on wording and grammar.

Comment: **small integers referring to counting within a small range should always be written as prose.** J.E. Littlewood (A mathematician's Miscellany, p. 39) humbly disagrees. I don't know the official position of his long time co-author who left us one of the most exquisite samples of English prose among other works, but I suspect it would not be very different either. The only real rule is that you try to do what does make sense, try not to do what does not, and don't insist that your way to distinguish between the two is the only correct one. Everything else is allowed :).